# Difference between Window Service, WCF Service application and ASP.NET web service application?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, windows-services, service, wcf

I don't know this is a right forum for my question or not?

I am new in Web Services. Today i just open VS2008 and found 3 type of SERVICE project

1. Window Service
2. WCF Service application
3. ASP.NET web service application

Please help me to find out the difference between these three projects?

When should we decide which type of project?

Answer (score 3):

Very short explanation:

- Windows service is as it states a service running on Windows OS. For example, indexing service running on Windows machine is a Windows service.
- Asp.NET Web Service is a service that can only be used via http and is hosted on server.
- WCF is a framework, layer or platform that enables you to create multiplatform services that can communicate with each other. WCF services supports more protocols. Can be hosted by server, application or used by other services. You can use WCF to create a web service or a windows service.

A newer and easier approach for creating lightweight web services is the stateless Web API. I suggest you download VS 2017 Community Edition, so you are not stuck with only those choices.